# Symfony 3: Testing form type submission with an entity with default values

Tags: php, symfony, testing, symfony-3.4

In Symfony's [How to Unit Test your Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/unit_testing.html) document is quite straight forward.

But I got a problem.

I have an doctrine entity with some default values. And a form type which is bound to the model. I mean `'data_class'` is the entity. In this case, when I call `$form->submit();` and `$form->isSynchronized()`, then the default values are gone. And the `$this->assertEquals($object, $objectToCompare);` fails.

How can I test a form type which is bound to a model class with some default values?

I suspect this is a bug. When the form type instance is created in `$this->factory->create(TestedType::class, $objectToCompare);`, the default values of `$objectToCompare` should be applied.

Or, should I create an extension to handle that?

Here're the example codes. To simplify the code, I changed the doctrine entity into the simple model.

#### The model

For comparing, I added 2 properties: one with the default value and the other without.

```php
// AppBundle/Model/TestObject.php
namespace AppBundle\Model;

class TestObject
{
    private $test;
    private $test2 = 'default value';

    public function getTest()
    {
        return $this->test;
    }

    public function setTest($test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function getTest2()
    {
        return $this->test2;
    }

    public function setTest2($test2)
    {
        $this->test2 = $test2;
    }
}
```

#### The form type

It is straight forward.

- adding 2 text type fields and 1 submit type field
- set default option `'data_class'` to the model

```php
// AppBundle/Form/Type/TestedType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use AppBundle\Model\TestObject;

class TestedType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('test', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('test2', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => TestObject::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

#### The testing

It's little modified version of [How to Unit Test your Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/unit_testing.html).

- `$object` is populated with property access
- checking fields existence is omitted.

```php
// tests/AppBundle/Form/Type/TestedTypeTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Form\Type\TestedType;
use AppBundle\Model\TestObject;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

class TestedTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = [
            'test' => 'test',
        ];

        $objectToCompare = new TestObject();
        $form = $this->factory->create(TestedType::class, $objectToCompare);

        $object = new TestObject();
        $propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        foreach ($formData as $key => $value) {
            $propertyAccessor->setValue($object, $key, $value);
        }

        $form->submit($formData);
        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($object, $objectToCompare);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have `test2` in the form, Symfony will automatically "handle" an empty value for the form field as `NULL`. You would need to omit `test2` or supply the default value to the form before it is submitted. ie `$formdata = ['test2' => $objectToCompare->getTest2()]` or in the `FormType` as described in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/use_empty_data.html#option-1-instantiate-a-new-class Though it would depend on what is occuring in your `parent::configureOptions($resolver);` as I do not believe it is needed in this context.

Comment: To clarify; I mean you would need to define the `empty_data` of each form field you added, since submitting `""` in a text field is an acceptable value . `$builder->add('test2', TextType::class, ['empty_data' => $builder->getData()->getTest2()])`